# Search for a field in a collection on firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query a collection using an email and to get the document id of a specific document where the email id matches. The code that I used is

```
checkUserExist = async (email) => {
 var id = await Firebase.firestore()
  .collectionGroup('requestBeta').where("email", "==", email).get()
  .then((querySnap) => {
    if(!querySnap.empty){
      
      querySnap.forEach((doc)=>{
        return doc.data();
      })
      
    }
    else{
      return null;
    }
  })
  return id;
}
```

I have to check whether a document with a specific email field exists in the database and if it exists return the doc id else return null. Note that the function on called, the returned value is stored in a variable. In the present code, this returns a promise with a result undefined.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you expect this function to do other than return undefined.  You might want to add some logging and explain what it's actually doing so we can follow along. Bear in mind that we can't see your database or observe this code running.  You'll have to explain that in your question.

Comment: Just added a few more details if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems with what you're doing here.

First, `doc.data()` doesn't return a document ID.  It returns the entire contents of a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) as a JavaScript object.  If you have a DocumentSnapshot, you should just use its `id` property to get its ID.

Second, returning a value from inside an inner `forEach` function doesn't return anything from the outer function.  It just returns a value from the inner function, and the loop continues.  The returned value is lost entirely.

You have a minor third problem in that you don't need to use `then` inside of an async function.  There is generally no need to use `then` when `await` alone will do.

You can rewrite this function much more simply and correctly:

```
checkUserExist = async (email) => {
  const querySnapshot = await Firebase.firestore()
    .collectionGroup('requestBeta')
    .where("email", "==", email)
    .get()

  if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
    return querySnapshot.docs[0].id;
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution actually works but a small clarification. Even though we are tucking in the async and await in the function, it returns a promise. I need to get the returned value in a variable. how can we get that part done? Thanks

Comment: All async functions return a promise.  That can't be changed. It allows for any amount of async behavior to occur in the body of the function.  On top of that, you can't make the result of a function that returns a promise into an immediate result.  The caller will always have to deal with a returned promise.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that the return inside the forEach result is simply being thrown away, I think that is this case a map would be more useful so you can map the document data into an array of documents and return that; something like this:

```
checkUserExist = async (email) => {
  var id = await Firebase.firestore()
  .collectionGroup('requestBeta').where("email", "==", email).get()
  .then((querySnap) => {
   if(!querySnap.empty) {      
     let result=querySnap.map((doc)=>{
       return doc.data();
     });
     return result; //return the results of the doc.data operations
  } else return null;
})
```

}